# How does HTML5 local storage determine the domain used to store values?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, uiwebview

I'm working on a hybrid native/Cordova iOS app. The app has a native core which downloads
items of HTML5 content from a server and displays them in a Cordova web view.

Unfortunately I'm running into problems with local storage - the key value pairs from all the separate
items of content are being stored together, because the domain for all locally stored HTML files is the same. 
This means that it is possible for one item of content to overwrite the data stored by another, if they are using the same keys.

I don't write these items of content, and would prefer not to place arbitrary restrictions on the use of local storage
on the developers who do.

I've tried examining the contents of the `window.location` object. The `hostname` property here returns the domain correctly when I log `window.location.hostname`, but setting it is clearly not an option since this reloads the page.

I've also attempted to look at the standard implementation of the `getItem` and `setItem` methods using the Safari web console, but the output indicates that those methods are implemented natively.

Ideally I'd like some way to set the domain in JS. I suspect however that this isn't possible because it would make it too
easy for an attack page to get at local storage key pairs that don't belong to it. Nevertheless, it would be useful to know definitively if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's something you can do on the JavaScript side. You should probably do it on the native side.

I wonder whether you use native code to fetch content from different domains and then display them in Cordova as local content. If that's the reason different contents from different domains mess up, just stop fetching remote content for local display. Remote content should stay as remote content. You can use normal web view to load remote domain, or embed them in iframe inside Cordova. Don't pull remote content and run them in local context.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there would be no way for javascript to do such a thing, i believe maybe using ajax would probably allow that but don't know how/if Cordova would interact as desired with it. I have developed several apps using apache servers and php along side native code for IOS and it definitely has helped with a lot of storage issues. but i am not a personal fan of Cordova and use the single view/or other settings in Xcode for that (but thats a personal preference)